# How to get data into the HTML page of an ExtensionSidebarPane?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have successfully created a [ExtensionSidebarPane](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ExtensionSidebarPane) which displays some data I have in stored in local storage:

saving the data:

```
localStorage.setItem('savedDataForReview',JSON.stringify(savedDataObject));
```

creating and updating the panel:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane("Data Reviewing Panel", 
function() {
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    'localStorage.getItem("savedDataForReview")',
    function (result) {
       pane.setObject(JSON.parse(result));
    }
  );
});
```

This works nicely. However I now want to improve the pane to have some tables and buttons, so I need to use HTML instead of just setting a JSON object. So I need to use

```
pane.setPage('html/my_reviewing_pane.html');
```

in place of the `setObject` line.

This works, however I can't seem to get access to local storage from within that pane HTML page.
If I include some javascript to access my saved data `localStorage.getItem('savedDataForReview')` then it returns null.

How can I pass data into the HTML page on an ExtensionSidebarPane? I imagine this is a scoping issue but I am not sure how I can get around it. I can't even easily build the HTML from within the function where the data is in scope, because `setPage` takes a local file path rather than an HTML string.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: It's URL origin of the script's page/environment that defines access to DOM storage. The html page you're supplying must be running in a different origin. Try switching to chrome.storage.local API instead of localStorage. Another approach would be [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm Very handy, I didn't know about [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), that looks perfect for my needs here. Will check it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with using a background script and messaging passing. Thank you [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the pointers.

I added a background script `background.js`, adding to the `manifest.json`:

```
...
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"],
    "persistent":false
  },
...
```

In my `background.js` script I added the following code so that it can receive messages from anywhere in the extension (content scripts, panel JS or pane JS):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(rq, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (rq.action=="getData") {
    sendResponse(getData());
    return true;
  } else if (rq.action=="deleteData") {
    sendResponse(deleteData());
  } else if (rq.action=="storeData") {
    sendResponse(storeData(rq.data));
  } else {
    console.log('received unrecognized request:');
    console.dir(rq);
    sendResponse(null);
  }
  return true;
});

function storeData(object) {
  localStorage.setItem("savedDataForReview",JSON.stringify(object));
  return true;
}

function getData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedDataForReview'));
}

function deleteData() {
  localStorage.removeItem('savedDataForReview');
  return true;
}
```

Then within my content script I send storage messages to the background script like this:

```
function getData(callback) {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "getData"}, function(resp) {
    callback(resp);
  });
}

function storeData(callback, data) {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "storeData", data: data}, function(resp) {
    callback(resp);
  })
}

function deleteData(callback) {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "deleteData", data: data}, function(resp) {
    callback(resp);
  })
}
```

```
storeData(function(response) {
              console.log(`response from storing data was: ${response}`);
            },data);
```

And in my pane's HTML page `my_reviewing_pane.html` I include a javascript file:

```
<h2>Reviewing Pane</h2>
<div id="review_table">&nbsp;
</div>
<script src="my_reviewing_pane.js"></script>
```

In that javascript file `my_reviewing_pane.js` I access the stored data by sending a message to the background script like this:

```
function getData(callback) {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "getData"}, function(resp) {
    callback(resp);
  });
}

getData(function(savedDataFromStorage) {
  let tableDiv = document.getElementById("review_table");
  console.dir(savedDataFromStorage);
  // now set HTML content into tableDiv.innerHTML using data from savedDataFromStorage...
});
```

Finally I create and set the pane from within the javascript of my devtools page:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane("Reviewing Pane",
    function (pane) {
      pane.setPage('my_reviewing_pane.html');
    }
);
```

I decided to use [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) rather than [Chrome storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) because I didn't need syncing and didn't want the size limits - but I think Chrome storage looks more powerful for a lot of use cases. See [this article](https://dev.to/milandhar/chrome-local-storage-in-extensions-4k9m).

Hope this is useful to someone else.